# Kafka Streams: a map not repartitioning co-partitioned data

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a KStream from an underlying topic that has type [K3, V]. K3 is a key composed by three fields, namely K3(a,b,c). However the topic is partitioned only by a subset of the fields of the key, namely K2 (a,b).

Now, I'd like to create a KTable to connect with and use in my PAPI Processor. I want this KTable to aggregate by K2(a,b). Aggregation just collects values into a Set.

For doing that, I'd have to use "map" function for converting my keys from K3 to K2. This will (try to) repartition data (although actually data will remain in the same partitions since it will also use K2 as partition key) by creating a new repartitioned topic, see "test-customerStoreName-repartition" in topology below.

```
  Sub-topology: 0
Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000 (topics: [test-customerz])
  --> KSTREAM-MAP-0000000003
Processor: KSTREAM-MAP-0000000003 (stores: [])
  --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000006
  <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000
Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000006 (stores: [])
  --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000005
  <-- KSTREAM-MAP-0000000003
Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000005 (topic: test-customerStoreName-repartition)
  <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000006
```

Is there a way I can do this aggregation without having to repartition via map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the DSL, this is not possible, as you cannot tell the library that repartition is not required. There is a KIP that proposes to add such a feature: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-759%3A+Unneeded+repartition+canceling

You would need to use Processor API directly because Processor API does not any auto-repartioning.

You could also "hack" something: after the `map()` the returned `KStream` can be casted into a `KStreamImpl` type and then, via reflections you can set the internal flag `repartitionRequired` to `false`. But this is a hack!